# db.collection.find() How to get the number of Documents?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku

I am trying to build a basic app using Node.js/Heroku with MongoDB/mLab, where a record is supposed to be added to a collection each time it is run. Here is the relevant code:

```
.........

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  //res.status(200).send('I dream of being a website.  Please star the parse-server repo on GitHub!');
  topDisplayFunc("index", res);
});

.........


function topDisplayFunc(displayPage, response) {
  MongoClient.connect(databaseUri, function(err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;

    db.collection('XCollection', function (err, collection) {
      collection.find().toArray(function(err, items) {
        if(err) throw err;

        response.render('pages/' + displayPage, {
          dataArray: items
        });

        collection.insert({number: collection.count}, function (err) {
          if(err) throw err;
          db.close();
        });
      });
    });
  })  ;
}
```

I start by removing XCollection from the list of collections.

The first time the page is visited XCollection is created with a record inside, XCollection then contains one document looking like this:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "544e6f91d22e2e001171d117"
    }
}
```

The second time it is visited, another record is created, XCollection then contains one more document:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "544e6f92e22e2e001171d118"
    }
}
```

As one can see, the field number does not appear.

If I change this line of code:

```
collection.insert({number: collection.count}, function (err) {
```

to this one:

```
collection.insert({number: collection.count()}, function (err) {
```

Then the added documents change look to something like:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "544e6f93e22e2e001171d119"
    },
    "number": {}
}
```

This time the field number appears, but with no value.

The code should add a document containing 0 the first time it is run, 1 the next time, then 2, then 3 ...etc...
But it does not work. Only some garbage is added each time in the newly created document. What should I change?
I need to say that all I have tried fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying a zillion possibilities and searching a bit more on the net for some slightly different ways of approaching the problem I ended up by finding a solution. In case it may be useful to someone else I put it here.

```
function topDisplayFunc(displayPage, response) {
  MongoClient.connect(databaseUri, function(err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;

    let theCollection = db.collection('XCollection');
    theCollection.count().then((count) => {
        theCollection.insert({number: count}, function (err) {
          if(err) throw err;

          db.collection('XCollection', function (err, collection) {
            collection.find().toArray(function(err, items) {
              if(err) throw err;

              response.render('pages/' + displayPage, {
                dataArray: items
              });

              db.close();
            });
          });
        });
    });
  });
}
```

If someone has some interesting comment to make. Please feel free to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You are closing the DB connection without waiting for the `insert` to complete.

```
collection.insert({number: collection.count}, function (err) {
  // err handling...
  db.close()
});
```

Comment: Note.... you can just leave the database connection open instead of opening and closing it on each request

Comment: Even when following these suggestions,this syntax still does not work: collection.insert({number: collection.count}, function (err) {....

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing more of your code.  Do be aware that if you are using mongoose, `collection.insert` bypasses the Schema defaults and validation.  Depending on how you have written your Schema, you may get better results just doing a save on the model or calling `collection.insert(new XCollection({number: collection.count}).toObject(), function (err, result) {` where `XCollection` is your mongoose instantiated Schema Model.

Comment: I am not totally sure what kind of code you want me to add. But in the meanwhile I edited the post and added a bit more context, hoping it will help someone to see what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Sorry @Michel -- I'm stumped.  I'd probably try the following: A) Leave the database connection open B) Try explicitly putting in a number, e.g. `collection.insert({number: 0}, function (err) {`.  Does that work? C) Try `items.length` instead of `collection.count()`

Comment: I ended up by finding a solution, you can take a look if you are interested. I posted the answer.